# Not Connecting to the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server Management Studio on my machine and once it was succesfully installed, I tried to connect to the local Database Engine but I was not succesful connecting to it it showing up an error showing as Cannot connect to the Local or having Network Related problems in the connection. I got a question here once I download the SQL Server management studio Do I need to do something else to get connected to the Local SQL Server.

Thanks,
Pranay.

Comment: When you say "local database", do you mean an instance on your workstation, or a database on another server? Have you tried ping/telnet to the machine in question, to see if you can connect to the machine on the correct port?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need by default you can connect to local machine. You might have a problem connecting from other machine in the network if TCP is not enabled, but local should work.

Make sure you typed your 'sa' password correctly or use Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in Windows Services? There is the service **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)** and **SQL Server Browser** which must be running.

Comment: I checked the Windows Services and I didn't find both the services running and can I know How to make both the services to run.

Comment: You said: **"didn't find the services runnning"**, so....can you see the services in the list?

Comment: No I didn't see the Services running

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Sql Server Configuration Manager` and make sure that **SQL Server** is running. Otherwise right click and click `Start`.

[image]

And sometimes you need to **Enable TCP/IP** in your `Protocols` again in your `Sql Server Configuration Manager`

[image]

Comment: In the SQl Server Configuration Manager when I click the SQL Server Services I'm not able to see whether it's running or not in the right hand pane and even when I do the right click it's not showing the start option to start the SQL Server.

Comment: Did you click `View` menu then `Detail`?

Comment: Yes I did but not seeing anything there

Comment: Is there any access rights are coming in to the play restricting my access to the sql server.

Comment: Try to Run as Administrator when you run Sql Server. Or did you really successfully install SQL Server in the 1st place? ;-)

Comment: I tried running as administrator and I'm not succesful I'm thinking of uninstalling the SQL Server and Reinstall it again to see whether it may solve the problem for this Do you got any resource to follow during the installation process.

Comment: Try this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2009/11/13/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-r2-express-edition-november-ctp.aspx) or this [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXJP4D503Tk). And for sql server 2012 link [here](http://www.soheib.com/technical-knowledge/sql-server-2012-express-installation-tutorial/).

Comment: Edper Thanks for the support I UnInstalled the SQL Server 2008 and installed the 2012 version using DVD Drive and it's working fine now. The link you provided for the 2012 version helped me alot Thanks so much....

Comment: Glad to be of help @pranay.GOD bless.